# Rmagick isn't montaging images using 'write' or 'montage' functions

Tags: ruby

I am trying to combine two images side by side into one using rmagicks montage and/ or write but it always just produces 4 images and i cant figure out why after quite a lot of googling.

```
require 'rmagick'

class CSV_Reader

  attr_reader :file

  def initialize(rows)
    @rows = rows
    @row_number = 0
    extract_images
  end

  def extract_images
    @rows.each do |row|
      imageURLs = []
      row.each do |image|
         imageURLs.push(image[1])
       end
       create_image_list imageURLs
    end
  end

  def create_image_list urls
    image_list = Magick::ImageList.new( urls[0], urls[1])
    create_image_montage image_list
  end

  def create_image_montage image_list
    columns = 2
    rows = 1
    marginsBetween = 20
    background = '#000000'
    image_list.montage {
      self.geometry = '+' + (marginsBetween/2).to_s + '+' + (marginsBetween/2).to_s
      self.tile = columns.to_s + 'x' + rows.to_s
      self.background_color = background
    }
    # image_list.write("bin/images/montage #{@row_number}.jpg")
    @row_number += 1
  end
end
```

Also once it goes through this process and writes the images separately it doesn't stop loading when viewing on local how or terminal. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was a fool as always: this works well

```
  def create_image_list
    @image_list = Magick::ImageList.new( @urls[0], @urls[1])
    create_image_montage
  end

  def create_image_montage
    @image_list.append(false).write("assets/images/montage#{@counter}.jpeg")
    @counter += 1
    # add_watermark
  end
```